# My convert the JSF is not working

Tags: jsf-2

Recently I created an application with JSF, I believe to be all right code line. could someone help me? I do not know where to be to identify the error.

```
<h:outputLabel value="Data de  Checagem" />
            <h:panelGroup>
                <h:inputText id="dataChecagem"
                    value="#{estoqueBean.itemEstoque.dataChecagem}"
                    label="Data de Checagem" converter="com.algaworks.SmartDate"/>                  
                <h:message for="dataChecagem" showSummary="true" showDetail="false" />
            </h:panelGroup>
```

this is my class to convert

```
package com.algaworks.cursojsf2.converter;

import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.faces.application.FacesMessage;
import javax.faces.component.UIComponent;
import javax.faces.context.FacesContext;
import javax.faces.convert.Converter;
import javax.faces.convert.ConverterException;
import javax.faces.convert.FacesConverter;

@FacesConverter("com.algaworks.SmartDate")
public class SmartDateConverter implements Converter {

    private static final DateFormat formatador = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");

    private Date getDataHoje() {
        Calendar dataHoje = Calendar.getInstance();
        dataHoje.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
        dataHoje.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
        dataHoje.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
        dataHoje.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
        return dataHoje.getTime();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        Date dataConvertida = null;

        if (value != null && !value.equals("")) {
            if (value.equalsIgnoreCase("hoje")) {
                dataConvertida = getDataHoje();
            } else {
                try {
                    dataConvertida = formatador.parse(value);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    FacesMessage msg = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR,
                            "Data incorreta.", "Informe uma data correta.");
                    throw new ConverterException(msg);
                }
            }
        }

        return dataConvertida;
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        if (this.getDataHoje().equals(value)) {
            return "hoje";
        }
        return formatador.format((Date) value);
    }

}
```

This is the error message found in my browser

Expression error: Object named: com.algaworks.SmartDate not found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this one :

```
 <h:inputText id="dataChecagem"
                value="#{estoqueBean.itemEstoque.dataChecagem}"
                label="Data de Checagem">
 <f:converter converterId="SmartDate"></f:converter>
</h:inputText>
```

And change :

```
@FacesConverter("SmartDate")
```